# Scala: How can I get the name of a variable class in a function?

Tags: scala

I'd like to do something like `def foo[V] : String = { V.getName }` but of course this isn't correct. I'm using the name of the name of the class to find a file that contains a serialized instance of the class in the file system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def className[V](implicit ev: ClassTag[V]) : String = ev.runtimeClass.getName()
```

Usage

`className[String]` gives `java.lang.String`

`className[Map[String,String]]` gives `scala.collection.immutable.Map`